# Jenkins - acces to executable from builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to add following step to jenkins job: once all building and testing steps passed i want to store created executable and make it accessible via web interface. E.g. for each build there should be icon to download *.rar file with executable. I know that there is plugin to do that, but can't remember its name.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option that you can execute after the build: `Archive the artifacts`, you can access to your files from the workspace in the directory you want.